Jest unit test running on Jenkins terminates intermitently lagger filesystem
I have a suite of around 13,000 test cases that I run in parallel. While the tests execute successfully on my local machine, the Jenkins job intermittently terminates with the following error:
Jenkins error: JENKINS-48300: if on an extremely laggy filesystem, consider -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400
Jenkins Machine Configuration:
Memory: 8 GiB
CPU: 2500

What I’ve Tried:

Running tests sequentially
Executing the script with node expose-gc

Does anyone have any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
